# How to cancel collectionView gestures, while touching a slider inside a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom slider inside a collection view. I change the value of the slider with touchesMoved. the slider works great when it is not in a collection view, I only need to start sliding inside its view and then I can continue sliding while moving my finger down or up outside of its view and it still works, but when it is in a collectionView once my finger gets out of the sliders view it stops and the collection view scroll is activated. How do I stop the scroll view gestures and continue with my slider?

Comment: is it a horizontal or vertical collection view?

Comment: It is a vertical collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found the answer myself. here it is:
I added this function in my cell class

```
func getParentCollection() -> UICollectionView?
{
    let collection = self.superview as? UICollectionView
    return collection
}
```

and my slider had completions and I do this:

```
self.secondaryVolumeSlider.didBeginTouch = {
        self.getParentCollection()?.gestureRecognizers?.forEach({ (gesture) in
            gesture.isEnabled = false
        })
    }
    self.secondaryVolumeSlider.didEndTouching = {
        self.getParentCollection()?.gestureRecognizers?.forEach({ (gesture) in
            gesture.isEnabled = true
        })
    }
```

So when I start touching the slider I turn off all the gestures of the cells superview, which is the collection view and when I end sliding I turn them back on.